# prevent java transformer from replacing 

Tags: java, transformer-model

I have this XML file

```
<test>&#13; &#xD; &lt;</test>
```

and i am tranforming it with the java code below, the xslt file just makes a copy of the xml

```
public class XMLTransform {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new File("file.xml"));
            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(new File("trans.xsl"));
            SAXTransformerFactory transformFactory = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
            Transformer transformer = transformFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");         
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            transformer.transform(source,result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

my problem is that java replaces the canonical carriage return **&#xD** with the **&#13** which is the ascii character.

Any help on how to preserve the canonical name for the carriage return?

Comment: &#xD; is not "canonical". Can you a cite an authority that says it is? And explain why it matters? This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that SAXON transformer does not make this modification. 
thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

you do realize that those are the exact same character, just in decimal form (`&#13`) vs. hexidecimal form (`&#xD`) (nothing to do w/ ascii per se).

Comment: yes i do realize it. but is it possible to preserve the canonical one? in anyway possible...

Comment: is there any transformer.setOutputProperty option that will help me on that? maybe i missed something...

Comment: @user685415 - what makes one "canonical" as opposed to the other?  that in a spec somewhere?

Comment: is there anyway way to preserve the hexadecimal? should i change a transformer or something? im really in need...

Comment: i doubt there is a way to control that with the standard java xml libs.  yes, you would probably have to look for a thirdparty lib to change how the entities are written.

Comment: @user685415 - the oracle jdk impl is a modified form of xalan, so i doubt you will achieve anything going that route.

Comment: if anybody has any ideas for me to try...pls..im getting in a dead end.